# reactjs paypal-buttons-v2 Uncaught Error: Detected container element removed from DOM

Tags: reactjs, paypal

currently i setup paypal payment and everything works good but got one error here:

```
Uncaught Error: Detected container element removed from DOM
```

I declared const price with usestate and on change i display the paypal button. I did this because i also got error if the price is 0 so i hide it when price is < 1.. I also tried here to add some class and tryed with display:none or opacity:1 .. I know this can work even like this but i would like to get my errors clean..

```
{price > 0 && (
  <PayPalButton></PayPalButton>
)}
```

package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-button-v2

Best regards..

Answer (score 2):

That type of error happens when the button is removed and regenerated too quickly.  It's not necessarily a problem since the regenerated button may still work, but you should avoid rendering one too soon if it is going to change right away by something re-rendering a new one.

Would also recommend using the newer and official `react-paypal-js` instead; storybook here: https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default

Comment: Is there any solution you think that will help me? I also tryed a multiple examples like i mention in first posts but i didnt solve it.. I must to hide them becase i also get error if user try to pay when price is 0..